# Delete CoreData objects after POST request

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm using RestKit 0.20.3 with CoreData to cache the results from my web services.
I need to delete from CoreData all the objects that are not in the response so I use `[RKObjectManager addFetchRequestBlock]`. Everything works fine when I do GET requests but when I do POST requests the objects are not deleted in CoreData, I think because `deleteLocalObjectsMissingFromMappingResult` is done only with GET requests.

I understand that, in a RESTfull architecture, POST requests are used to update an entity on the server side but in my case the web service provides search capabilities and takes a lot of optional parameters in POST.

Is there a way to configure RestKit to do the deletion even after POST requests?

If not, do I need to perform the deletion by hand at the end of each request or is there another better way?

Comment: You debugged to see `deleteLocalObjectsMissingFromMappingResult` isn't called? I expect it should be called as it's part of the mapping operation.

Comment: the body of deleteLocalObjectsMissingFromMappingResult contains the following code witch cause a return without any delete in case of non GET request      `if (! [[self.HTTPRequestOperation.request.HTTPMethod uppercaseString] isEqualToString:@"GET"]) {  
        RKLogDebug(@"Skipping deletion of orphaned objects: only performed for GET requests.");  
        return YES;  
    }`

Comment: Cleanest option is to do the deletion yourself then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This currently is not supported. The best option here would be to add an `RKRequestMethod` property to `RKManagedObjectRequestOperation` that specifies the HTTP methods that are permitted for use with managed object cleanup. This would be a simple change to implement.

Please open up an issue on the RestKit Github requesting the feature and we'll see about getting it included in 0.21.0.

Comment: 2 years later, but can you remember why you restricted it to `GET`s only?